# add a "added to cart message" to page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

need some help, I added "the add to cart short code" to some items on my page.  I wanted to add the add to cart notices to page as well.

I don't have a lot of experience with wordpress or woocommerce.  I added the class  "woocommerce-message" to a div and display this function

which does display a message, but it shows the div when there is no message

can someone one please show me the correct way to do this, a step by step example?

Thanks I appreciate any help

Answer (score 3):

I believe your page needs to have `wc_print_notices();` on it. Then the notices should appear when they are needed.